# How to update profile pic in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created an api where one can upload pic for profile along with rest of the details. My problem is that if one wants to change the pic, how can it be done.
At present, I am able to save pic for the first time.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    User = get_user_model()
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="accounts/images/", null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=False,
        null=True
    )
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        current_user = request.user
        param = request.data
        profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=current_user.pk)
        if profile:
            serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=param)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save(user=current_user)
                new_data = serializer.data
                return Response(new_data)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class ProfileView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            # exist then update
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile, data=request.data, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            # not exist then create
            serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=param)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save(user=request.user)
                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

or just use [UpdateAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updateapiview):

```
class ProfileView(UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks!. One more thing I want to know is that how to delete the pic from the folder that is being replaced.

Comment: Also what happens with `partial=True` parameter?

Comment: partial=True will allow you update some fields of your Profile instance instead of all fields.

Comment: Yoo this is super helpful, its a same that everytime I come to this part I am always getting the error messages or am removing the data in other fields. Thank you so much for this